# Which interrupt occurred when I using wait_event_interruptible_timeout?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

How can I know which interrupt break waiting on function **wait_event_interruptible_timeout()**? 
I've got -ERESTARTSYS, but I need to know exectly which one cause return of function.

Comment: The process is woke up by signal(software interrupt).

Comment: Ok, but can I know which signal?

Comment: why do you want to know which signal？

Comment: to handle them or avoid sending in wrong time

Comment: signal is handled by signal handler, why do you want to handle it by hand? Also, signal is sent asynchronously, process may receive a signal at any time, so there is no wrong time at all.